# How to practice open-mindedness

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

Is there a good method or procedure in which I can use to practice having an open mind? I'm just looking for a way in which I can progress when it comes to looking at things from a neutral perspective.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be about practical life advice in a way that's not well-suited to the scope of philosophy.SE.

Comment: Rational assessment. The distinction of what is true from what is "true to [you;me;us;them]"  The analysis of statements as true or false, particularly where you are tempted to conclusions of right and wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to look at an issue from as many different perspectives as possible. Find out what other people think about it. Look at what people in different countries, different languages, different cultures, different times have to say about it. Don't assume that because Aristotle, Marcus Aurelius or Montaigne lived a long time ago they have nothing useful to contribute.

When you have what you think is a good explanation or account of something, keep looking for alternatives. Many people when they encounter an issue sieze upon what they consider to be the most obvious explanation and then cling to it like a dog with a bone. There are always alternatives.

Try to falsify your beliefs, not just confirm them. It is tempting to look for evidence that you are right, but it is just as important, if not more so, to look for evidence you are wrong.

Don't be afraid to challenge the prevailing concensus, or the assertions of the prevailing authorities. Even experts get things wrong. The history of medicine, for example, is full of false claims and harmful remedies that persisted for a long time because nobody dared to challenge expert opinion.

Remember that theories and models are just useful fictions, so don't get too attached to them. Reality is always more messy than theories allow for.

Guard against groupthink. It is common to spend most of your time with people you agree with. You should spend more time reading and talking to people who disagree with you.

If others disagree with you, don't assume they are just ignorant or have vested interests. Imputing a vested interest to someone is an easy game to play, and anybody can play it, but ultimately it proves nothing and is unhelpful.

Challenge your own preconceptions about things. Be realistic and honest about your own knowledge. It is easy to have a strong opinion about something you know little about. Self-criticism is difficult to do but essential to avoid bias.

Don't be afraid to change your mind about something. It is not a sign of weakness. Equally, don't suppose that because you used to believe something and changed your mind that it must be false. "I used to think that..." is not a good argument.

Never stop learning. Learn from a wide variety of different fields and subjects and don't over-specialize. Learn about the common forms of cognitive bias, so you become less likely to fall victim to them yourself.

Always bear in mind that your own views, no matter how strongly you believe them, may be false. It is extremely easy, and common, to become overattached to your own opinions. Being sure you are right is positively correlated with low intelligence and ignorance. Smart, knowledgeable people know their limitations and are more cautious in their claims.

Comment: Thank you. I feel this is very important lately regarding the current political situation and people's beliefs on it. A lot of people seem to Base their opinion based upon what they hear without having done unbiased, independent research.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be open minded, you should make a serious effort to be open to critical discussion. This requires posting your ideas in public and being willing to discuss your own ideas and any ideas you cite. It is common for people to post some source they regard as an authority and act as if that ought to end the discussion: this is close minded. For more details, see:

http://www.fallibleideas.com/paths-forward.

Answer (score -2):

Just make yourself comfortable. Generally speaking, people raised in health, happiness and security are overall affectionate and have ambitions higher than such basic needs as food, money, social status, etc.

The more you know, the less you will judge because people generally will not curse the fig tree when they realize that the time of figs is not yet. Learn everything you can get your hands on with the aim of having pleasures: art, history, literature, music, science, technology and foreign languages are all sources of immense pleasures. Exercising these skills later in life are extremely rewarding when food and sex begin to lose savour.

Keep in mind that some highly intelligent people have very odd immune systems, and their brains tend to be very sensitive. If you don't like some people or stuff for no apparent reason, don't blame yourself too much; it might be just that [your immune system is trying to protect you](https://news.virginia.edu/content/shocking-new-role-found-immune-system-controlling-social-interactions).

> It is a bad thing for intelligence, and ultimately for character, to let instruction be influenced by moral considerations.
>
> --Bertrand Russell. [Education and The Good Life.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000PGWCO6)